# Files not having any content in after a header() download

Tags: php, header

I'm trying to create a download so that a user clicks on "down" it downloads a certain file from their account to their computer, I'm currently using this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename("users/$username/$file_folder/$file_name"));
header("Content-Type:" .$file_type);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Cache-control: private");
header("Connection: close");
header("Content-Length: ".$file_size);
```

The problem is, the file is downloading, but it's just empty, there is no content in the file

The code before this is just an if() and a while loop with database records.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not showing any code that is actually outputting any data, so troubleshooting that part is difficult

Comment: This just sets the headers, you need to actually echo the file contents.

Comment: why not just say `$filename` instead of that whole basename construct?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is, the file is downloading, but it's just empty, there is no content in the file, sorry for forgetting to mention this, I'll edit.

Comment: @Aiden: Can you show the rest of the code?  Where do you actually `echo` the contents of the file?

Comment: I haven't echoed out the content :o, I though I just needed to send out the headers for the download?

Comment: @Aiden: That's why it's blank.  The headers are just headers.  You still need a body.

Comment: I see, so what else do I need to incorperate in order for the file to have contents?, I'm sorry for wasting your time with my beginner-like questions

Comment: @Aiden: You can use [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to echo the file contents.

Comment: Wouldn't using an echo display the contents on screen though?, this is the part I do not understand

Comment: @AidenRyan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2426/discussion-between-rocket-and-aiden-ryan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is empty, because you never output the file.  These `header` calls are just the header, you still need a body for a file to be correctly downloaded.  You can use [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to echo the file contents.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename("users/$username/$file_folder/$file_name"));
header("Content-Type:" .$file_type);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Cache-control: private");
header("Connection: close");
header("Content-Length: ".$file_size);

// echo the file, this will make the download work
echo file_get_contents("users/$username/$file_folder/$file_name");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing something like below: (unless the file is very large, in which case you would chunk it out)

```
$filename = 'path/to/file/file_name.txt';

echo file_get_contents($filename);
```

Alternatively you could populate a variable with the data you want put out into the file and simple echo it out like so:

```
$data = "begin\n";
$data .= "first line\n";
$data .= "another line\n";
$data .= "last line";

echo $data;
```

The content would be put out there AFTER your headers.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't think of readfile(). That may be better since it will echo out as well.  However, if you need to chunk out a large file it may bring down the server. file_get_contents allows you to specify offset and maxlength.

Answer (score 0):

after you send the headers you need to actually push out the file content...

see this
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Don't you want [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead?  [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) writes to a file, not the screen.

Comment: That presumes OP is actually writing data out to a file. If he's building a string with a loop, then just an `echo` would do.

Comment: rocket is correct, i was hasty.  @marc also correct really the problem is op is not writing anything beyond headers.